# Failed Laravel dependency injection in controller method

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have a model called **Dbtable** which isn't injected when used like this:

```
public function showEditDbTableForm(Request $request, DbTable $table) 
{

}
```

it only works when I do this:

```
public function showEditDbTableForm(Request $request, $id)
{
    $table = DbTable::find( $id );
}
```

Same thing happens even when I rename DbTable to DbTble

P.S.: please don't be rude with me as I'm new to Laravel framework

Comment: what do you mean by "it isn't injected", is there an error? But if you are talking about 'route model binding' the route parameter name has to match the method parameter name

Comment: The second parameter of the showEditDbTableForm is the id for a DbTable record. So, when using DbTable $table I expect the model to be retrieve automatically

Comment: What error do you get if you do it in the first way?

Comment: reread the 'route model binding' documentation, the route parameter name must match the method parameter name (for implicit binding), might be some other goodies in there too :)  but guessing since i can't see a route definition

Comment: @lagbox Ok I see what you mean

Comment: can you create a reply ?

Comment: i will create an answer for you, np

Comment: np, good luck and have fun with laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Implicit Route Model Binding you need to make sure the parameter in the method signature has the same name as the route parameter you want to bind.

```
Route::get('widgets/{widget}', 'WidgetsController@show');

public function show(Widget $widget)
```

*Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name.*

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Routing - Implicit Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#implicit-binding)

Answer (score 1):

In  RouteServiceProvider class add

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('db-table', App\DbTable::class);
    // db-table correspond your rout parameter
}
```

see official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing **Explicit Binding** section